# How can I edit a range variable without editing the cells on the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a userform which edits the values of certain tables within my workbook.

In the userform code I have this:

```
Public vTable As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set vTable = Sheet1.Range("Table1")
vTable.Cells(1, 1).Value = "New Value"

End Sub
```

The problem is that when a value in the `vTable` variable changes, the value in the cell on the worksheet changes as well.

I want to prevent this from happening; none of the changes should be applied to the worksheet until the user clicks the "Done" button on the userform.

Comment: use array instead range: 1) `Public vTable As Variant`. 2) `vTable = Sheet1.Range("Table1").Value` 3) `vTable(1, 1).Value = "New Value"` and finally, when user press button, 4) `Sheet1.Range("Table1").Value = vTable`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your issue. The code you provided initializes the `UserForm`, assigns a `Range` object then writes out "New Value". Where are you making changes to the `vTable` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the contents of the range into a Variant array, modify the array as appropriate, and then, when the button is pressed, slap the array back onto the sheet.

So you need:

```
Public vTable As Variant
```

Then:

```
vTable = Sheet1.Range("Table1").Value 'load the contents of the range into an array
vTable(1, 1) = "New Value" ' modify array
```

When the button is pressed, slap the array back onto the sheet:

```
Sheet1.Range("Table1").Value = vTable
```

Comment: I now see that @simoco basically wrote the same answer in a comment to the question. (I hate when people do that!) Hopefully the explanation in my answer adds value.

Comment: Made the answer Community Wiki [as advised](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/119775).

Comment: I'm not sure what version you are on but the `Sheet1.Range()` is not working in 2007. I had to qualify with `Sheets("Sheet1").Range()`

Comment: Well, have you created a range named "Table1" like the OP has? Because if you haven't, then of course it's not going to work.

Comment: Yes I did, but that wasn't what was causing the error (for me). VBA was having trouble with the `Sheet1` _unspecified variable_ vs the `Sheets("Sheet1")` _object_

Comment: `Sheet1` is the default VBA object name for the sheet whose Name property is "Sheet1" (as visible on its Excel tab), at least in all English language Excel versions I've tried 2003-2010 (and apparently in the OP's as well). Maybe yours is different? Look in your VBA Project browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to make some loops to take the values out of the cells and put them in their own array. Then you can modify the array of non cell values.

```
Dim i, j
Dim newArr() As Variant


ReDim newArr(Range("data1").Rows.Count - 1, Range("data1").Columns.Count - 1)

For i = 0 To Range("data1").Rows.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To Range("data1").Columns.Count - 1
        newArr(i, j) = Range("data1").Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value
    Next j
Next i

''Change value
''Put values back into cells

For i = 0 To Range("data1").Rows.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To Range("data1").Columns.Count - 1
        Range("data1").Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = newArr(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

This seems complicated, but I can't seem to strip the values off the cell object to make changes to them without the the change going back to the cell value.

Comment: Looping through cells is not only overly complicated, it's very slow. Instead, read/write the whole thing at once.

Comment: I tested @simoco's code that was in the comment before I put this answer up and it was not working. I wasn't aware that the `.Value` operator worked like that.